# How to change image in TableViewCell when searching records?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have array which contains Name, image url and many values, and i want to change image when searching result. here only changing name values. so how to add image value in array?

```
 if (searchText.text.length == 0) {
    isSearching = NO;
}
else
{
    isSearching = YES;
    filterdResult = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSString *str in [SQLData valueForKey:@"Name"]){

        NSRange heroRange = [str rangeOfString:searchText.text  options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        if (heroRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            [filterdResult addObject:str];
        }
    }
}
```

Here, SQLData is a NSMutableArray and it contains JSON Values, like name imageURL, but here it only add Name value, how can i add imagevalue too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the structure of SQLData ? is it holds all the records ?
You need to loop each RECORD and not each NAME.

this way, when you get ONE RECORD, you check the NAME field in that RECORD
if the NAME value is rangeOfString:searchText.text THEN
you add the RECORD to the filterResults.

this way you got filter array of RECORDS. in every RECORD you will have all the values you need (name, image and others)

RECORD can be for example NSDictionary ("name":nameValue, "imageURL":imageURLValue..etc). 
again I don't know exactly what SQLData holds, but I hope this give you the direction of what you are looking for.

Comment: here is a SQLData contains http://dpaste.com/25BJ8MZ it holds json values

Comment: if SQLData is 1 record, just get the name value into str without using FOR loop.
If you have ARRAY of SQLData only then you need to loop, get each record and check the name value.

Comment: No no, SQLData contains 400+ records i have just give you format or sample what value it holds, i want all values and key by filter.

Comment: what is the object that hold 1 record ? NSDictionary ?
so you need to change the FOR to :
for (NSDictionary * oneRecordDic in  SQLData)

if(oneRecordDic objectForKey:name   == what you looking for)
 then add oneRecord to recordsFilterArray

Comment: so solve this.
1. FIRST loop EACH RECORD. and print the NAME.
2. check if NAME is what you looking for and add RECORD(and not str) to filterRecordsArray

Comment: I have tried with this but when i add in array it add first object from SQLData.  http://dpaste.com/20YS9ZZ

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137272/discussion-between-user1105951-and-vivek-goswami).

Comment: Prepare your data in nsarray, and then call   [tableView reload];